# Strange PATH behavior in win-bash

Tags: bash

I installed win-bash on Windows 7 and I'm getting the following strange behavior.

```
bash$ cat C:/Home/.bashrc
PATH="C:/Program\ Files/GnuWin32/bin:C:/Windows/system32"

bash$ . C:/Home/.bashrc

bash$ echo $PATH
C:/Program\ Files/GnuWin32/bin:C:/Windows/system32

bash$ which diff
which: no diff in (.;C;\Program\ Files\GnuWin32\bin;C:\Windows\system32)

bash$ which ls
which: no ls in (.;C;\Program\ Files\GnuWin32\bin;C:\Windows\system32)
```

Why are the PATH values different?

The PATH value returned by `which` contains `.:C;\Program\ Files\GnuWin32\bin`

Note:

- the ".:" in the beginning that does not exist in the bash PATH value.
- the "C;" (not C:) contains a semi-colon instead of a colon.
- the `which` PATH value has back slashes (`\\`) instead of forward slashes (`/`)

Where is `which` sourcing these PATH values?
I can not find any other .bashrc or .profile or profile files anywhere on the machine.

In addition,

```
bash$ diff file-abc.txt file-xyz.txt
1c1
< abc
---
\> xyz

bash$ ls file-abc.txt
file-abc.txt
```

Both `diff` and `ls` work on the command line even though `which` can not find the `diff` or `ls` commands.

Both `diff` and `ls` are located in `C:/Program\ Files/GnuWin32/bin`
But `which` returns `C;\Program\ Files\GnuWin32\bin` (note C; not C:) which is why `which` can not find `ls` or `diff`.

Again, where is `which` sourcing these PATH values?

In my bash script named Try1.sh I have these lines.

```
\`diff $CURRENT_FILE $NEW_FILE\`
\`ls $CURRENT_FILE\`
The diff command fails with
Try1.sh: 21c21: command not found
```

The `ls` command succeeds. Why?

Both `diff` and `ls` live in the same PATH location `C:/Program\ Files/GnuWin32/bin`.

Comment: It probably uses Windows' PATH variable. Click on start->Right Click computer, select Properties. Click Advanced System Settings then finally click Environment Variables. This is just a hunch, I've never used WinBash. I use cygwin.

Comment: I checked the Windows PATH variable and it's totally different. So thanks for the hunch but that is not it.

Answer (score 1):

Windows has a different search algorithm to UNIX-like systems.  On Windows the first directory to be searched is the directory which the parent program (.exe) was loaded from, then the current directory, then `C:/Windows/system32` is searched.  That's where the directory names are coming from.

The `path` environment variable is only used as a last resort!

For a full discussion on this, see [MSDN entry for CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

`which` is also showing the Windows path directory separator as `;`, rather than `:` which UNIX-like systems use.  Also, `/` or `\` are valid as a directory separator in a Windows path, but only `/` is valid on UNIX.

Also note that environment variables (like `path`) are not case sensitive on Windows, but on UNIX they are.

EDIT:  I have been trying to track down the source code for win-bash but can't find it.  I found *some* source code for `which` in GNUUtils, but can't be sure that it is the same version as you are using.  The version I looked at, 2.4, makes assumptions about Windows which are not necessarily correct.

After downloading the binary for win-bash, I found that the bundled `which` is indeed version 2.4, and looks the same as the source code I have been looking at.

It is a separate program and not integrated with the rest of the shell code.  To answer the question on directory separators and path separators, they are hard-coded for Windows (sys.h):

```
#define DIRSEP '\\'
#define PATHSEP ';'
```

The path is read from the environment variable using `getenv`.

Further edit:

The command

```
\`diff $CURRENT_FILE $NEW_FILE\`
```

is invalid.  It is capturing the output from `diff` and then trying to execute it.  `21c21` is the output from `diff`, and of course there is no such program as `21c21`.  Just use:

```
diff $CURRENT_FILE $NEW_FILE
```

Comment: Thank you for all the knowledge, but it doesn't solve my problem. Bottom line, how do I solve the error: Try1.sh: 21c21: command not found
The ls command succeeds but the diff command fails. Why? How do I get rid of the  C; in the path? Where is the C; coming from?

Comment: @user3145909: see "Further edit".  There is no C; in the path environment variable, it is an invention of `which`.

Comment: Thank you very much! one last thing. I'm getting the following error when I try to run the sort command from my script because it is using the wrong sort command because of the strange PATH value that's being used.<br>The error is "Input file specified two times." and it comes from the Windows sort command.                       bash$ which sort
C:\Windows\system32\sort.EXE
bash$ which diff
which: no diff in (.;C;\Program\ Files\GnuWin32\bin;C:\Windows\system32)

Comment: C:\Windows\system32\sort.EXE bash$ which diff which: no diff in (.;C;\Program\ Files\GnuWin32\bin;C:\Windows\system32) The reason it doesn't find the unix sort under C:/Program\ Files/GnuWin32/bin is because it's using that strange PATH value that contains C; How do I fix that problem?

Comment: bash$ ls -l C:/Program\ Files/GnuWin32/bin/sort.exe
-rwxrwxrwx  1 user 0 96256 2005-04-20 11:41 C:/Program Files/GnuWin32/bin/sort.exe
bash$ ls -l C;/Program\ Files/GnuWin32/bin/sort.exe
ls: C: No such file or directory
bash: \Program Files\GnuWin32\bin\sort.exe: No such file or directory